# Can't Parse Chromium Source Code with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I got Doxygen yesterday and was able to set it up (with graphviz) with one of my personal projects (which had none of the "special" comments that Doxygen usually uses to setup a document). However when I tried with the same settings on Chromium I got this error:

```
Preprocessing              C:/Chromium/src/build/Release/obj/global_intermediate/blink/DebuggerScriptSource.h...  
Parsing file   C:/Chromium/src/build/Release/obj/global_intermediate/blink/DebuggerScriptSource.h...  
Exiting...  
DE_PATH?  
C:/Chromium/src/breakpad/src/processor/disassembler_x86.h:45: warning: include file    third_party/libdisasm/libdis.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to   INCLUDE_PATH?  
input buffer overflow, can't enlarge buffer because scanner uses REJECT  
*** Doxygen has finished
```

Well I found this webpage that says that the programmer of Doxygen would have to fix the input buffer problem themself: http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Error-Input-buffer-overflow-td1147.html So perhaps I could find a utility to split up files or something for this.

Question 0: Before you bother to read any other questions, the reason I want to use doxygen to generate dependency graphs to make looking through the code easier, so is there any better alternatives I should be considering (preferably one that I can just set a few settings and press a button with)?

Chromium builds within Visual C++ Express 2010, although it is Chromium (a million things can go wrong) so the header file issue is not that surprising. Question 1: Anyone know what is happening with the header file?

Question 2: But what is this DE_PATH?, I looked through all the settings and searched with Google and found nothing useful.

Comment: I think that `DE_PATH` is a truncated output and it should be `INCLUDE_PATH`.

Comment: That is likely as there is a INCLUDE PATH setting, thanks. It is a bit unusual for a line to be truncated from the front though.